# PowerShell string - what is use of pipe in string

Tags: powershell

1. How its returning only two services even $service is a single string. How -match works here and what is use of pipe (`|`) symbol..?

```
$service = "WebClient|WinRM"
Get-Service |where{$_.name -match $service}
```

2. If I remove the pipe (`|`) between service names and put some other character, nothing is returning.

```
$service = "WebClient,WinRM"
Get-Service |where{$_.name -match $service}
```

Comment: The ```-match``` operator compares strings using a “regular expression” which is a set of rules for defining *patterns* for matching a string - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#-match-and--notmatch. The pipe symbol is a special character that means “match any of these values” - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference#alternation-constructs

Comment: @santhoshn, if you search the web for "test regex online" you will find several online tools for testing regular expressions.  I personally use regex101.com all the time.  You place your regular expression in the top center box, and just below that is where you place the text you are testing for matches on.  On the right upper is an "EXPLANATION" box that can sometimes really help in understanding.  And just below that box is the list of matches that your regex found in the text you are testing. Also, lower right is a quick reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it doesn't directly answer your question about the pipe if you are simply looking for a selected group of services the following is more direct.

```
Clear-Host
$service = "WebClientd","WinRM","DHCP"
get-service -ServiceName $service -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
   Select Status, DisplayName
```

Output:

```
 Status DisplayName                              
 ------ -----------                              
Running DHCP Client                              
Running Windows Remote Management (WS-Management)
```

Note: the -ErrorAction suppresses the error where the service doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks RetiredGeek for providing alternate solution :)